# Ubuntu One can't connect: "root mismatch"

Tags: 12.04, ubuntu-one

[image: root mismatch]

There was a problem with a previous account of mine, so I created a new one. (There's hardly anything in it, so I figured creating a new account isn't a problem.) In fact, I'll gladly close that account, if I knew how, and use only my newly created one.

I'm struggling to the Ubuntu One application. I've managed to get it to see my new account name and email address, but when I try connect, the above screenshot appears. How do I fix this?

EDIT: As a matter of interest, I found where to close my previous account. So, now I have this (and only) account running, but as I said above, it won't connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Before proceeding:** Make sure that you have a backup of your local Ubuntu One folders, if you have anything in there that you'd like to keep.

Run the following commands:

```
u1sdtool --quit
rm -rf ~/.local/share/ubuntuone/syncdaemon
u1sdtool --start
u1sdtool --connect
```

Information found [here](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/what-does-the-root_mismatch-error-mean/).